# Windows zoom-level resets during login

Tags: windows-10-preview, 4k-resolution

I'm using three 28 inch Dell 4k monitors with Windows 10. Every time I reboot, login, or return from the lock screen, Windows adjusts the zoom level from 150% to 350%, even though it says 150% is 'recommended'.  As you might have guessed a zoom level of 350% is unusable, so I have to change it back to 150% multiple times per day.

[image]

Comment: report it in the Feedback app of Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 Build 10158 fixed this problem